# differences in the Introspection for applicationContext xmls between windows and linux?

Tags: spring

I'm currently developing a modularized application with spring. currently we have a core with a main method that looks for the application context xml files of any modules using the following line:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext c = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/spring/core.xml", "META-INF/spring/*-module.xml");
```

the annoying part is the server deployment. on our windows based developer machines all modules are found at startup, meaning we get multiple lines like:

```
o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from file [...\META-INF\spring\legacy-module.xml]
```

on linux (debian lenny), there is only the entry for the core context xml.

my guess is I'm doing something wrong, so how do i configure my application context to properly look for all *-module.xml files in my classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the pattern to

```
classpath*:META-INF/**/*-module.xml
```

now it works. Be warned: **/*-module.xml does not work. the Spring documentation states that the first folder is required otherwise the classloader will not find the resource.